# XCode project: how to remove / add files from terminal (script, command, etc)

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, terminal, xcodeproj

Is there a way to remove files from or add files to a XCode project without using XCode? That is, is there any terminal command or program to do it? I know I can do `cp` `mv` and `rm` to add / remove files but they are not reflected in the actual project file.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, but Xcode is AppleScript-able and can probably add/remove files that way.

Comment: If you know Ruby: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Answer (score 4):

There's a Ruby Gem called xcodeproj which allows manipulation of an XCodeProject at the command line.

Check out [Using the Xcodeproj Ruby Gem](https://larryaasen.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/using-the-xcodeproj-ruby-gem/) which provides an example of adding a file to a project.

```
# Open the existing Xcode project
project_file = product_name + '.xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.new(project_file)

# Add a file to the project in the main group
file_name = 'Message.m'
group_name = product_name
file = project.new_file(file_name, group_name)

# Add the file to the main target
main_target = project.targets.first
main_target.add_file_references([file])

# Save the project file
project.save_as(project_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

try building after you copy them in using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

don't know if it will work, but worth a try :)